# Reactjs Pops undefined in component

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have created react components for a form. I passed data as props from GetSteps component to PageHeader component. Then I will able to use that data from the PageHeader. Also I passed same data from the GetSteps component to YourDetails component. But the data didn't pass to the YourDetails component. I cannot find the error. any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

```
class GetSteps extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {data: ''}
}
// componentWillMount() {
//     var lang = [];
//     $.each(this.props.value.Languages, function(k, v) {
//         return lang[k] = v;
//     }.bind(this));
//     this.setState({ data: this.props.value.Languages })
//
//     console.log(this.state)
// }
render()
{
    return (
        <div className="page-content">
            <div className="container">
                <PageHeader title={this.props.value.Title} subtitle={this.props.value.SubTitle} f={this.props.value.PreferredLanguage}/>
                <YourDetails title={this.props.value.Title} preferredlang={this.props.value.PreferredLanguage}></YourDetails>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

this is where I pass data as props

```
function PageHeader(props){

return(
    <div className="page-header">
        <span className="page-header-icon icon-world"></span>
        <h3 className="title">{props.title}</h3>
        <h4 className="sub-title special">{props.subtitle}</h4>
    </div>
);
```

}

this is where I get data from GetSteps component

```
class YourDetails extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        havePartner: 'yes',
        UserFirstName: "",
        TravelPartnerName: "",
        AmwayLocation: "",
        Title: this.props.title
    };
    console.log(this.props);

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleOptionChange = this.handleOptionChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
handleSubmit(event){
    console.log(this.state);
    event.preventDefault();
}
handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'radio' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    });
}
handleOptionChange(event){
    this.setState({
        havePartner: event.target.value
    });
}
render() {
    return (
        <div className="main-content">
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div className="field dropdown requiredField">
                    <label className="left">
                        Your prefered language
                    </label>
                    <div className="middleColumn">
                        <select name="language"
                                value={this.props.preferredlang}
                                onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                className="dropdown requiredField align--left">
                            <option defaultValue value={this.props.preferredlang}>{this.props.preferredlang}</option>
                            <option value='g'></option>
                            <option value='fdg'></option>
                            <option value='df'></option>
                            <option value='dfg'></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="field requiredField align--left">
                <label>
                    Your First Name
                </label>
                    <input
                        name="UserFirstName"
                        type="text"
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange} />

                </div>
                <div className="field optionset requiredField travel-partner align--left">
                    <label className="left">
                        Did you have a travel partner?
                    </label>
                    <ul className="optionset requiredField travel-partner align--left">
                        <li>
                            <input type="radio"  value="yes" checked={this.state.havePartner === 'yes'} onChange={this.handleOptionChange} className="radio"/>
                            <label>Yes</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input type="radio" value="no"  checked={this.state.havePartner === 'no'} onChange={this.handleOptionChange } className="radio"/>
                            <label>No</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div className="field text requiredField align--left">
                <label className="left">
                    Your travel partner's first name
                </label>
                    <input className="text requiredField align--left"
                        name="TravelPartnerName"
                        type="text"
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                    </div>
                <div className="field text">
                    <label className="left requiredField">*Required Field</label>
                </div>
                <div className="Actions">
                <button type="submit" value="Submit" className="action nolabel " >
                    <span>Proceed to Day 1</span>
                    <span className="progress"></span>
                </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

this is where I didn't get data from GetSteps component

```
class Step extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {data: ''}
}
componentWillMount() {
    var link = document.getElementById('step').getAttribute('link');
    $.getJSON( link+"VideoBuildForm", function( data, status ) {
        fieldValues.PreferredLanguage = data.compilation.PreferredLanguage;
        fieldValues.AmwayLocation = data.location;
        fieldValues.Languages =
            $.each(data.languages, function(k, v) {
                return data.languages[k] = v;
            });
        fieldValues.Title = data.title;
        fieldValues.SubTitle = data.subtitle;
        this.setState({ data: fieldValues });
    }.bind(this));


}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <GetSteps value={this.state.data}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

this is where I pass data to the GetSteps component

Comment: Where did you pass the props data to GetStep ? Also example props data. can you provide a bit more detail please

Comment: I updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Try using `props.title` in your constructor instead of `this.props.title`.